# Microsoft SQL 2014 express Unable to attach database, .mdf, due to error 2571

Tags: sql, database, data-transfer

I am trying to attach a database from a computer running Microsoft SQL 2005 express to another running Microsoft SQL 2014 express. I detached it fine but when I bring both the .mdf and the .ldf files over and try to attach it I get a message that reads:

```
 "User 'guest' does not have permission to run dbcc checkprimaryfiles". Error 2571
```

I thought it could be a issue with file permission so I made sure to check both files to see if they were allowed to be editable by the current User profile. They were, so I thought it could have been an issue when I detached. It didn't seem to be.

How do I go about transferring this database correctly?

Comment: There is a fix listed on the support site to install the latest SP for SQL2005: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2268122

Comment: This question held its own answer: "...issue with file permission..." for my problem.